# How to create new custom logger function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, logging

I want to `create new custom logger function.`
we have default functions available like below

```
    logger.debug('debug message')
    logger.info('info message')
    logger.warn('warn message')
    logger.error('error message')
    logger.critical('critical message')
```

How can create a new custom logger  function using custom code.
custom logger like below example -

`logger.success('success message')`

Answer (score 3):

Given that the current logging library doesn't really cater for this, the only way I can conceive that you'd be able to achieve what you are asking is to make a subclass of the logging.Logger class and define your own success method.

For example:

```
import logging

SUCCESS = 5
logging.addLevelName(5, 'SUCCESS')


class Logger(logging.Logger):
    super(logging.Logger)

    def success(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.isEnabledFor(SUCCESS):
            self._log(SUCCESS, msg, args, **kwargs)


formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s')
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

log = Logger('mycustomlogger')
log.setLevel(SUCCESS)
log.addHandler(ch)

log.success('Hello World')
```

Comment: What does the `super` call do here? I usually only see that called inside method definitions.

Comment: in hindsight it might be doing nothing at all since we are already inheriting from the specified class